# Skipping lines and selecting wrong cells while reading CSV file

Tags: python, csv

So I have a csv file that has tons of games and info about them and I'm trying to save the game's publisher and the ESRB rating. But for some reason when I print them out it'll randomly skip games and chose wrong cells.

My code:

```
def simpleLoop(file_name):
output = []
input_file = open(file_name, "r")
for line in input_file:
    cells = line.split(",")
    output.append((cells[7], cells[13]))
i = 0
while (i <= 10):
    print(output[i]) # testing what values i get
    i += 1
```

[Screenshot of csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fm9Pi.png)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mOlX.png)

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6Lcp.png)

Any help is appreciated thanks!

**Edit: Solved with the help of SimoN**

For anyone else facing a similar issue make sure you specify exactly where you want to split. In my case I split at commas but there were commas inside some of the cells. So to fix this I changed:

```
cells = line.split(",")
```

To

```
cells = line.split('","')
```

Which makes python split after each cell because cells end with a double quote then a comma and the next cell starts with a double quote

Comment: is there any reason you're not using pandas' `read_csv()` ?

Comment: @JuanC well, for starters, it is totally unnecessary and a giant dependency simply to read a csv.

Comment: You should be using the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html) module to parse csv data.

Comment: Thank you for speaking on behalf of @ccf913. They seem to be new, and working on a leisure project, so they'll probably be installing pandas anyways, which is the easiest way for someone that is new to python..

Answer (score 2):

There are commas inside some of the cells and you are splitting on these. When you opened the CSV in Excel (or whatever you used) it knew not to split on these as they are surrounded by quotes. I'd suggest using the Python csv module so you can do the same.

Comment: Please accept my answer if it fully solved your problem.